# PHPExcelReader Can not write to DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im having a go with the phpexcelreaderclass from http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/ and I have been following this tut: http://rackerhacker.com/2008/11/07/importing-excel-files-into-mysql-with-php/

Now all seems to be going well but it dosn't seem to insert anything into the database? It echo's back to me the data from the sheet, so I guess its reading it and displaying it back but its just not writing to the MySQL database.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
    $data->read('Export.xls');

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("excel",$conn);

    for ($x = 2; $x <= count($data->sheets[1]["cells"]); $x++) {
        $rep_num = $data->sheets[1]["cells"][$x][1];
        $description = $data->sheets[1]["cells"][$x][2];
        $repair_type = $data->sheets[1]["cells"][$x][3];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO data (`rep_num`,`description`,`repair_type`) 
            VALUES ('$rep_num',$description,'$repair_type')";
        echo $sql."\n";
        mysql_query($sql);
}
```

I guess its something obvious I'm sure, thanks in advance.

Comment: Ensure that the $rep_num, $description and $repair_type values are escaped, in case they contain quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (rep_num, description, repair_type) VALUES ('$rep_num','$description','$repair_type')";
```

make sure your field names are correct.

Comment: o dear really bad mistake on my part, I missed the '' on $description beginners error for sure, thank you your answer put me on track :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us. :D

Answer (score 0):

Check your mysql_query method result like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

[php.net - mysql query description](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)